# Powershell: How to combine formatted variables into a string with no whitespace?

Tags: powershell, removing-whitespace

From numbers ($m in 0..59) and ($s in 0..59) i wish to construct strings on the form:¨

```
YYMMDD_HH$m$s,
```

but with leading zeros for $m and $s whenever $m<10, $s<10. (These are names of folders I wish to copy from.)

If I write

```
foreach($m in 0..59)
{
foreach($s in 0..59)
{
Write-Host "YYMMDD_HH"$m.ToString("0#")$s.ToString("0#")
}
}
```

I get output on the form

```
YYMMDD_HH 00 00
YYMMDD_HH 00 01
```

and so on. My question is: How do I do this so that there are no whitespaces in the output?

Answer (score 2):

Another version using the Format operator:

```
foreach($m in 0..59)
{
    foreach($s in 0..59)
    {
        "YYMMDD_HH{0:00}{1:00}" -f $m,$s
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-f` operator

```
foreach($m in 0..59){
    foreach($s in 0..59){
        "YYMMDD_HH{0}{1}" -f $m.ToString("0#"),$s.ToString("0#")
    }
}
```